# Is there any reasonable initial/invalid value for a pid_t?

Tags: c, gcc, posix, default-value, pid

Turning on the `-Wextra` flag to `gcc` seems to have the effect of disallowing partial initialization of `struct`s. E.g.:

```
// main.c
#include <pthread.h>

typedef struct S {
  int i;
  pid_t pid;
} S;

int main( int argc, char* argv[] ) {
  (void)argc;
  (void)argv;
  S s = { 42 };
  (void)s;

  return 0;
}
```

```
$ gcc --version && gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Werror ./main.c
gcc (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 6.3.0 20170516
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

./main.c: In function ‘main’:
./main.c:12:3: error: missing initializer for field ‘pid’ of ‘S {aka struct S}’ [-Werror=missing-field-initializers]
   S s = { 42 };
   ^
./main.c:6:9: note: ‘pid’ declared here
   pid_t pid;
         ^~~
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
```

**Is there any reasonable initial (invalid) value for a `pid_t`?** I'd always felt that since `pid_t` is opaque, one ought not make any assumptions about flag values.

If there is no reasonable initial/invalid value for a `pid_t` **is there some other good/widely-used programming practice to not hit this error?**

---

Note: specifically interested in learning if there are options that do not involve assigning an arbitrary value that is assumed invalid until a separate validity flag variable is set true, e.g.

```
typedef struct S {
  int i;
  pid_t pid;
  bool valid;
} S;

S s = { 42, 9, false };
```

Comment: It's only an error because you've enabled `-Wextra` and `-Werror`.  That's a rather extreme combination.  `-Wextra` warns about several things that tend not concern me.  I might use that combination transiently to ensure that I consider the diagnostics it produces, but I'm more likely to turn on at most one of those, and I would not use the two together outside of a development context, myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pid_t` is not opaque. Zero and all negative values are explicitly exceptional (used e.g. by [`waitpid`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/waitpid.html) to represent particular classes of processes to wait for) and arguably 1 is exceptional too since the specialness of -1 prevents 1 from being a process group id you can use normally (traditionally, pid 1 is the init process).

For your purpose, 0 seems like the most reasonable choice.

Answer (score 8):

`pid_t` isn't completely opaque, it's defined by POSIX ([2.12.1](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_12)) to be a signed integer type, and valid process IDs are always positive integers ([3.300](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html)).

I would use either `0` or `-1` as a default value, since neither can be a valid process ID.  `fork()`, for instance, returns 0 to indicate that the current process is the parent, and `-1` on error.